# Error en laravel: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 SAVEPOINT trans2 does not exist

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

tengo una consulta respecto a Laravel 5.7, es un proyecto multi tenancy, el caso es que al generar las migraciones se crea el admin sin problemas, el problema viene cuando intento crear un cliente, no se crea la DB de cliente y sale el errorr:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 SAVEPOINT trans2 does not exist
```

el problema parece venir del lado de la base de datos en mi caso de Mysql, espero alguno haya solucionado. gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolvi con el querido docker, de la siguiente manera.

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  php-apache:
    container_name: my_container_name
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    working_dir: /var/www/app
    volumes:
      - ../:/var/www/app
  database:
      image: mysql:5.7
      restart: no #always
      container_name: my_container_name_to_db
      environment:
        MYSQL_USER: test
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: example
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
        MYSQL_DATABASE: my_db
      ports:
        - '3306:3306'
      volumes:
        - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
  db-data:
```

era la version de mysql al parecer, porque probe varias versiones, pero esta al fin me dio luz.